# PHP Curl Basic OAuth Getting Access Token

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl, oauth

I was trying to get access token from an API provided by an Indian Marketplace Flipkart, If i run the curl code in Putty SSH i am able to receive an access token, But if i am trying the same thing from PHP it's giving me 400 Error.

Code Used in SSH (This Works)

```
curl -u appid:appsecret https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token\?grant_type\=client_credentials\&scope=Seller_Api
```

I get Response

```
{"access_token":"1111-xxxx-22222","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":4926731,"scope":"Seller_Api"}
```

But when i try achieving the same thing using PHP Curl(which i learned online only) i get 400 Error

PHP Code Used (This Does'nt Work)

```
<?php
$username='appid';
$password='appsecret';
$url='https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token\?grant_type\=client_credentials\&scope=Seller_Api';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){   
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($output);
echo $status_code;
?>
```

There is no other output rather than a 400 (the status code) which is bad request.

I know i am close, i don't know what i am doing wrong.
Any Help would be appreciated.

PS: You can find the API Docs here https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/FMSAPI.html#third-party-application-integration

Comment: This line --> `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`.  Use `$ch`, not `$curl`

Comment: Ya i did that but its not going to help in my case since there is no redirection, but the code should be right :)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the problem, the url they mentioned in their docs does not work when we try to do the same thing using php curl.

The Phrasing of Url is Different in case of php

So The URL Should have been 
$url='https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Seller_Api';

and voila, i got my access token.

PS:Please Don't think i was impatient and asked the question too early before looking around, it's my second day fighting the same problem. But i got lucky today ;)